# Ethereum: Which endpoint can I use for testing?

Tags: python, web3.py

I am developing python project using web3.py.
Myetherwallet API is used.
I'm gonna test `get_balance()`.
[Here](https://www.myetherapi.com/) used endpoint is live net.
What is endpoint for testing? Can I use above descrived endpoint for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ganache ([link](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/)), a popular test network for Ethereum.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Excuse me, please tell me the test provider URI of that.

Comment: By default ganache uses localhost:8545 but it’s entirely configurable.